# gtest and lua incompatibility?

Tags: c++, lua, googletest

I regularly use gtest for automated testing of C/C++ code. I have started exploring adding Lua in some software for extensibility. The problem is that when I include both gtest and lua I end up not getting a running gtest program, but instead get a lua command prompt.

I am using Lua 5.1.5, and haven't tried it with 5.2 yet.

Here is a simple example:

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
extern "C" {
#include "lua.h"
}

using namespace std;

class lua_test : public ::testing::Test {

protected:
    lua_test(){}
    virtual ~lua_test(){}
    virtual void SetUp()
    {
    }

    virtual void TearDown()
    {
    }
};

TEST_F(lua_test, my_test)
{
}
```

I am suspecting that the issue is some conflict with defining main or something like that. Can anyone shed light on this?

I will continue to dig deeper and update if I figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I figured out the issue. I am using CMake to build my dependencies. I did this to build liblua.a as well. But when I created the CMakeLists.txt file I just included every header and source file without paying enough attention to lua's Makefile (that's what I get for being in a hurry). So I included lua.c which defines main. Once I pulled that out of liblua it started working as expected.